# Problems when the document submitted to hyperledger is larger than the couchdb limit. How to revert?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Currently I have a little bit custom Hyperledger Setup whith couchdb 3.2.2.
In one org the default limiting document size was not changed and stayed 8 MB and we got a transaction larger than that. The transaction failed. However, now when I try to submit new transaction to my chaincode/channel I get the following error

```
channel 'industrial-test' not found
```

Is it possible to fix/revert that without using backups?
Or should I submit a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Easier than expected.

1. Changed default.ini max_document_size in the misconfigured peer. (Only restarting this peer didn't work initially)
2. Restarted orderers and peers.
3. Fixed

Unfortunately, not sure which of these steps lead to the solution. And if this would work in a production environment.